# jquery find element with matching attribute-Value

Tags: jquery, attributes, selector, match

I try to keep it simple,

I have a hidden-html structure generated in an each loop, holding a video-title as text and a video id as `data-id=""` attribute

```
<ul id="videoholder" style="display:none;">
<li class="videodata" data-id="sD__BIzTVlE">great title</li>
<li class="videodata" data-id="GN8B2l3ouxc">even greater</li>
</ul>
```

in the same loop i´m generating textfields for changing the title of the Video looking like:

```
<input type="text" name="titel[0]" class="float videotitel" data-id="sD__BIzTVlE" value="great title" id="titel[0]" /></div>
```

now i need to bind changing a textfield with replacing the text in the `<li>` matching to the data-id

I tried doing so :

```
$('.videotitel').bind('keyup', function(){
var data = $(this).attr('data-id');
var title = $(this).val();  
$('.videodata[data-id*='data']').text(title) ;
})
```

but i´m not able to insert the variable `data`

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

anybody got a hint how to get this done ? 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to concatenated data within selector.

Change

```
$('.videodata[data-id*='data']').text(title) ;
```

To

```
$('.videodata[data-id*='+ data + ']').text(title) ;
```

Comment: yeah thats it too, thankss a lot, i will throw a dice who gets the "answered"